# Linq to XML file query not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

This is my XML file and I am  using linq and entity framework

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Projects>
  <Project ProjectId="JP001" Country="Canada" ProposedBy="Jim Priac"/>
  <Project ProjectId="KS12" Country="Canada" ProposedBy="Aya Suriour"/>
  <Project ProjectId="ANS16" Country="Malesia" ProposedBy="Gour martin"/>
 <Projects>
```

the linq query I am using is

```
   IEnumerable<string> Proposed_By = from project in xmldoc.Descendants("Projects").Elements("Project")
                                            where project.Attribute("Country") == "Canada"
                                             select project.Attribute("ProposedBy");
```

but I am not getting correct output

Comment: How do you load the xmldoc? And is it of XDocument or XmlDocument? Could be helpful if you showed the loading code as well.

Comment: @Jehof include </Projects>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First see if your file is getting
make corrections to your linq query

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath("filename"));
    IEnumerable<string> Proposed_By = from project in xmldoc.Descendants("Projects").Elements("Project")
                                    where project.Attribute("Country").Value == "Canada"
                                     select project.Attribute("ProposedBy").Value;
```

Comment: Ya @V2Solutions- MS Team

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare to the value of the attribute and not to the attribute itself.

```
IEnumerable<string> Proposed_By = 
        from project in xmldoc.Descendants("Projects").Elements("Project")
        where project.Attribute("Country").Value == "Canada"
        select project.Attribute("ProposedBy").Value;
```

I would however go a step further and also check if the attribute is there (since calling the `Value` property on a `null` object would result in an exception:

```
IEnumerable<string> Proposed_By = 
        from project in xmldoc.Descendants("Projects").Elements("Project")
        where project.Attribute("Country") != null 
              & project.Attribute("Country").Value == "Canada"
              & project.Attribute("ProposedBy") != null
        select project.Attribute("ProposedBy").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting output

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Value` with attribute names

Answer (score 0):

Another Way:
           It returns NULL if Value is not present.

```
 var Propposed_By = from project in xd.Descendants("Projects").Elements("Project")
                           where project.Attribute("Country").Value == "Canada"
                           select (string)project.Attribute("ProposedBy");
```